# "The different development paths" OR "the different developmental paths"

Tags: word-choice

I try to translate a Vietnamese document into English.
And I am confused with the term "**The different development paths**" OR "**the different developmental paths"**. Which one is appropriate?

"**The different development paths** of indigenous culture in the drainage basins of the Red River, Ma River, Ca River, and others converged and formed the Dong Son culture. This was the period that the first state in Vietnam was born under the form of a community, which was the basis for primitive tribes to develop into a nation."

Everyone, Could you help me, please?

Comment: I've removed the Vietnamese original text as we don't do translation here, and if someone answers based on that text, we don't share the ability to verify any answer. If you could clearly explain *in English* what the first phrase of that paragraph means, that would be a suitable reference point for us to answer from.

Comment: [I'm trying to translate a document]

Answer (score 1):

I don't see much scope<sup>1</sup> for different *meanings*, and both versions are syntactically fine, so it's primarily a matter of which you prefer - possibly influenced by [which is most *common*...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=development%20path%2Cdevelopmental%20path&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3)

[image]

---

<sup>1</sup> Probably some people will say ***developmental*** alludes more strongly to ***biological*** processes, and ***development*** is more strongly associated with "human enterprises" (people building cities or producing software, for example). But that's a very weak distinction, often neither intended nor perceived.

Comment: Hi! I upvoted your good answer! Someone downvoted it. The score of that answer was - 1.Now is 0.Your good answer does not deserve a downvote! Thank you very much for everything! I have written down your comments in the other question. Somebody downvoted again my answer and my question. I deleted it and I will edit it with more details. I wrote for you comments in the other question and Gotube deleted them before you see them! I am going to delete this comment when you see it!

Answer (score -1):

While **development paths** would be completely acceptable (and possibly even favored) in spoken American English, according to the dictionary, **development** is only a noun, not an adjective. **Developmental** is the adjective. So I believe you should say:

> The different developmental paths...